# User Profile Synchronization Service won't start

Tags: user-profile-service

I am trying to start the User Profile Synchronization Service on Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise on premises with no luck.
In the log there is the error below.
Do you know what the problem could be? Thanks

```
User Profile Application: SynchronizeMIIS encounters an exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.<>c__DisplayClass2.<IsTimerJobRunning>b__1()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.IsTimerJobRunning(UserProfileApplicationJob timerJob)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ILMProfileSynchronizationJob.Execute()
```

**EDIT:**
A bigger chunk of log is here:

```
02/03/2014 16:20:38.92* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetFileForRequest(HttpContext context, SPWeb web, Boolean exclusion, String virtualPath)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.InitContextWeb(HttpContext context, SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.GetContextWeb(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IEx...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.92* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...ecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompl...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.92* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...etion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)   31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.92  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           aiv4w   Medium      Spent 0 ms to bind 3356 byte file stream    31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.92  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.92  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution Time=77,4491590411631   31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres... 31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, ...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbst...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...rRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion,...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ... String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, ...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, ...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureContentFetched(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.GetFile(String virtualPath, Boolean fetchContent)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetFile(String virtualPath)     at System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider.GetFileWithCheck(String virtualPath)     at System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider.OpenFile(String virtualPath)     at System.Web.UI.DependencyParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)     at System.Web.UI.DependencyParser.GetVirtualPathDependencies()    ...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ... at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetDirectDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequ...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...estModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilatio...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...n.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)     at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Ex...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...ecute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr p...  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94* w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High        ...Handler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           aiv4w   Medium      Spent 0 ms to bind 22772 byte file stream   31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.94  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ahjkm   Medium      Spent 0 ms to send 22772 byte file stream   31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.96  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1618)                       0x28D4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-solution-resource-usage-log). Parent No ff9a1937-4c4f-4a3e-85d0-2668faed109e
02/03/2014 16:20:38.96  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1618)                       0x28D4  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job job-solution-resource-usage-log  31a8709c-1c93-404e-1e1a-c6b9240694c5
02/03/2014 16:20:38.96  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x1618)                       0x28D4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-solution-resource-usage-log). Execution Time=2.19078123057539    31a8709c-1c93-404e-1e1a-c6b9240694c5
02/03/2014 16:20:38.97  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Server               General                         ahjnd   Medium      Constructed a new async cache named Profile Property Cache  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.97  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk4d   Medium      UserProfileProperty_WCFLogging::Begin ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel 31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.97  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk35   Medium      MossClientBase_WCFLogging::Begin MossClientBase.ExecuteOnChannel    31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8077    Critical    "There are no instances of the Servizio profili utente started on any server in this farm. Ensure that at least one instance is started on an application server in the farm using the Services on Server page in Central Administration."  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk38   High        MossClientBase_WCFLogging:: MossClientBase.ExecuteOnChannel - Unrecognized exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEndpointAddressNotFoundException: Nessun indirizzo disponibile per questa applicazione.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoundRobinServiceLoadBalancer.BeginOperation()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk4f   High        UserProfileProperty_WCFLogging::Begin ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel threw Exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.MossClientBase`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   g11n    High        UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsCompatibleDatabaseSchema(ProfilePropertyData propertyData)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.RefreshProperties(Guid applicationID)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValueNow(K key)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.SPAsyncCache`2.GetValue(K key, Boolean asynchronous)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.InitializePropertyCache()   31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have f080adb1-75fc-487f-9d39-33f3b322196e     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have f080adb1-75fc-487f-9d39-33f3b322196e     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have f080adb1-75fc-487f-9d39-33f3b322196e     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have f080adb1-75fc-487f-9d39-33f3b322196e     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:38.99  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  Web Content Management          Publishing                      7fz3    Medium      Setting [Display] as the FormContext.FormMode for the current page  31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:39.00  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x06D8  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dka1    High        SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo--Proxy Name:Compan Search Service Application EndPoint: http://intraapp2:32843/5657eb61495b4077a48deef99da4526f/SearchService.svc    7da4709c-ac83-404e-1e1a-c42fd9ada4be
02/03/2014 16:20:39.00  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x06D8  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dk8z    High        SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetChannel--Channel Creation time: 0 7da4709c-ac83-404e-1e1a-c42fd9ada4be
02/03/2014 16:20:39.00  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x06D8  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium      WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://intraapp2:32843/5657eb61495b4077a48deef99da4526f/SearchService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ISearchServiceApplication' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/ISearchQueryServiceApplication/GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:4693164c-a8d3-453c-b704-aa10653ccad1'    7da4709c-ac83-404e-1e1a-c42fd9ada4be
02/03/2014 16:20:39.00  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have f080adb1-75fc-487f-9d39-33f3b322196e     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076e0a
02/03/2014 16:20:39.00  w3wp.exe (0x1300)                           0x1130  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have f080adb1-75fc-487f-9d39-33f3b322196e     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    31a8709c-3c8c-404e-1e1a-c1cfa3076
```

Comment: Can you share your ULS logs?

Comment: I've edite the file. That's all I could put

Comment: Is your user profile service app linked to a service application proxy? Is the service app proxy in the default Application Proxy Group?

Comment: This would also help the new users **[User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on 'Starting'](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/user-profile-sync-service-stuck-on-starting/)** and **[User Profile Synchronization Service Starting then Stopped SharePoint 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/)**

Answer (score 1):

Problems with the User Profile Synchronization Service are all too common. I find that 99% of the time the issue I'm having has a solution in Spencer Harbar's article [*“Stuck on Starting”: Common Issues with SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization.*](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx) Another excellent resource is his article [*Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization*](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx).

Please review both of these articles carefully and let us know how you progress.

Answer (score 1):

I followed under given URL which saved lot of my time. It is a very detailed article which also provided information about the user registration on Active Directory too. Hope this might help someone else to same few minutes.
http://www.windowstechupdates.com/user-profile-synchronization-service-not-starting-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

try to clear the config cache on the servers and try again?

if above not fixed the issue, then please try this post:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/60d1a022-6fb6-43f3-af78-cfd3e88e9bdb/cant-start-user-profile-sync-service?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 0):

Finally for me the below steps resolved the problem

- Giving temporarily domain controller permission to farm service account
- Cleaning cache

  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx

  ```
  Get-SPServiceInstance 
  $s = Get-SPServiceInstance GUID
  $s.delete()

  Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
  ```
- Restarting